# Unity Multi Display and Different Orientation(Resolution)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, winapi, orientation, resolution

I wanna make Multi Display's Resolution as 900 * 1200
and Main Display's Resolution as 1920*1080

How can i do that?

condition

1. monitor 1 is landscape, monitor 2 is landscape
2. play game
3. rotate monitor 2 to portrait using winapi (ex. user32.dll ChangeDisplaySettings etc.)
4. activate Display 2

when i play game after change display setting to portrait on window display setting
game work suitable

but change display setting using winapi
game not work suitable

Comment: What is the actual goal here? Display orientation is a windows setting that should correspond to the physical orientation of the display, not something any game or random application should mess with. If you for some reason want to draw things sideways to a monitor you can usually do that within the application by using some type of render transform.